# Spawning and destroying random platforms in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a doodle jump game in unity for fun and I have a question.

How could I change my script to spawn other platforms on top and destroy any platform that is under main camera.I'll let down my code for spawning random platforms

```
public class GradinariuZAHAR : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform Player;
    public GameObject platformPrefab;
    private float minimY = 0.2f;
    private float maximY = 1.6f;
    public int numberOfPlatforms = 200;
    public float levelWidth = 3f;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        GenerateChunk(.2f, 1.5f);
    }
    void GenerateChunk(float minY, float maxY)
    {

        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlatforms; i++)
        {
            spawnPosition.y += Random.Range(minY, maxY);
            spawnPosition.x = Random.Range(-levelWidth, levelWidth);
            Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Player.position.y > 160) {
                Debug.Log("acum");
                minimY = maximY;
                maximY = maximY * 2;
                GenerateChunk(minimY, maximY);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just attach the following script to your platform. It'll destroy the platform once its entire sprite is completely below the camera, exactly how you want it.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Platform : MonoBehaviour
{

SpriteRenderer sprite;
float bottomOfScreen;

private void Start()
{
    sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    var cam = Camera.main;
    var screen = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    var camWorldPos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(screen);
    bottomOfScreen = camWorldPos.y - cam.orthographicSize * 2;
}

private void Update()
{
    var height = sprite.bounds.size.y;
    var topOfPlatform = transform.position.y + height / 2;

    if (topOfPlatform < bottomOfScreen)
        Destroy(gameObject);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I've missed but it's not working.Do I need to do any changes in sprite renderer?

Comment: @VladFodor Sorry, I made a mistake in calculating the camera's y position. I corrected the code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @VladFodor The script is attached to the platform prefab, right? Also, is there anything else in that script, or does it look just like mine?

Comment: There is void GenerateChunk in same script with your script

Comment: @VladFodor No, why? Keep that in the GradinariuZAHAR script.